# Вылетает исключение

Tags: c#

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Вылетает исключение

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

```
public class Program
{
    static readonly string[] SizeSuffixes =
                      { "bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };

    static String ConvertSizeToString(Int64 file_size_byte, Int32 number_simbols_after_comma)
    {
        if (file_size_byte < 0) { return "-" + ConvertSizeToString(-file_size_byte); }

        int i = 0;
        decimal dValue = (decimal)file_size_byte;
        while (Math.Round(dValue, number_simbols_after_comma) >= 1000)
        {
            dValue /= 1024;
            i++;
        }

        return string.Format("{0:n" + number_simbols_after_comma + "} {1}", dValue, SizeSuffixes[i]);
    }

    private static string ConvertSizeToString(long v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertSizeToString(100005000L));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вызываете вариант `ConvertSizeToString` с одним параметром, который и выбрасывает исключение.

```
Console.WriteLine(ConvertSizeToString(100005000L, 2));
```

Comment: Или сделать так: `static string ConvertSizeToString(long v) { return ConvertSizeToString(v, 2);}`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно унаследовать и реализовать метод интерфейса, который вызывает ошибку.

Comment: Верный подход, или не вызывать то что не реализованно.